# Blank Page result from setting up a local testing server in Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: php

Thank you for entertaining my question. Irretentive as it may seam I have need to say I am a novice. On a Windows 8 machine running Dreamweaver CS6 with Apache 2.2.22 and PHP installed on the root c: drive in the following configuration: apache; htdocs; php. Testing Apache localhost "It works!"

I have set-up a Dreamweaver file "PHP_Basic-Lesson_001.php" containing the following lines:

```
<?php
$myAge = 30;
echo $myAge;
?>
```

The file "PHP_Basic-Lesson_001.php" is saved in folder apache > htdocs alongside index.htm
The c: root folder htdocs contains folder phptest

On activating the F12 key Dreamweaver procedure is followed in accordance with Adobe article "Setting up a local testing server in Dreamweaver CS5" The result at the URL is as expected:  file///C:/apache/htdocs/PHP_Basic-Lesson_001.php.

However the page remains blank. I have tried another approved snippet of code and this too fails to display.

I would be obliged gratefully to have a working answer.

Comment: You can't access a script via file if you want the php code to execute. It needs to be accessed via http. http://localhost/PHP_Basic-Lesson_001.php will probably work if you configured everything correctly.

Comment: @datasage is right - accessing the file directly won't execute the script, you have to request it from a server, in this case your own server at `http://localhost`.